# Windows Runtime Component can't load Newtonsoft.Json lib

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

I have a project with 2 solutions:
1. Universal JS App(Win10);
2. Windows Runtime Component(C#);
I try to add the Newtonsoft.Json lib to C# solution;
Code in WRP lib:

```
class Class1
{
    public string Test()
    {
          Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer x  = new JsonSerializer();
          return "Test";
    }
}
```

Code in js app(default.js):

```
var testRes = new Test.Class1().test();
```

When I try to run js app I get an Exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in version 1.1 of the tools.  Please install the update in this thread to fix the issue

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73f2d56d-9e8e-4b57-bcfa-0a972dfd75d7/update-11-generating-store-associated-package-fails-for-a-uwp-application-with-a-winrt-component?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues